# How to compile a cpp file directly from vim editor in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, vim

I've recently installed a vim editor in my Windows operating system.
I only know the conventional procedure i.e, creating the source file in the editor and running it from the command line. But,
I don't quite understand how to compile a CPP program directly from the vim editor.
when I run the command

:!g++ hello.cpp -o hello

from the vim command line, I get the following message

C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c (g++ hello.cpp -o hello)

Hit any key to close this window...

Comment: You can run programs with `:!`, e.g. `:! g++`

Comment: Do you want to compile a single file or do you actually want to generate an executable binary? Compiling is only part of creating the latter.

Comment: [Please dont post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/), and please [edit] your question to use proper markdown formatting

Answer (score 1):

I assume your version of Vim is windows version and not cygwin version.

First you need to install a compiler, and make sure it's in your PATH.

Also, read the documentation about quickfix window as this is the *integrated* vim way of compiling. `:!make` or `:!g++ ...` are not the way to go.

### MSVC

I don't suppose this is the compiler you have as I expect you'd have used Visual Studio in that case. Anyway, IIRC, there is a `msdev` compiler plugin you could load with `:compiler msdev`, then you should able to run `:make`.

Don't hesitate to complete my answer if you see errors.

### g++ through cygwin

There is a big advantage: gnumake is properly configured: in the console you could run `make foo`, and if you have  `foo.cpp` or `foo.c` and no `Makefile` in the current directory, this would compile the monofile project. In all cases, a `Makefile` is fine; and it's required with multiple source files.

The big problem: pathnames are not expressed in the same way. They need to be translated. I provide a way to do that in my Build-Tools-Wrapper plugin. Just execute `:BTW add cygwin`.

Then from vim, again type `:make %<`. That will translate into `:make foo` (assuming you're editing `foo.cpp`), which translates into `make foo`shell wise, which translates into `$CXX $CPPFLAGS $CXXFLAGS $LDFLAGS foo.cpp -o foo $LDLIBS` (or something like that).

Note: this means the options can be tweaked with: `:let $CXXFLAGS = '-std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra'`

BTW, if you have my build-tools-wrapper plugin, you can execute directly `:Make` instead of `:make %<`, or just `<F5>`directly, IIRC.

### g++ through mingw

The good news: no need to translate pathnames

The bad news, gnumake isn't correctly configured. This means that in the console `make foo` won't work. And consequently, this won't work from Vim.

This time, you'll either need a `Makefile`, or you'll need to tweak `'makeprg'` setting. Like for instance `:let &makeprg = 'g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17 -o %< %'` and then type simply `:make`.

Comment: Hi Luc, Thanks for the explanation. I am currently using g++ ( MinGW) . I don't know how to create a Makefile like that. Don't take me wrong, I'm new to vim. could you please tell me how to create a make file or just drop a link that I can go to and find the answer?

Comment: The screenshot of the first link I see in google with "write Makefile" seems good and simple enough to me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_r7i5X0rXJk