# How do I run cpp program directly from Vim?

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, vim

I've recently installed Vim on my Windows 10 and also the **g++ compiler** through **mingw**.
I want to directly compile and run my cpp program from Vim.
I've tried the following command.
`:!g++ hello.cpp -o hello`
below is the image for the reference
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KORJe.jpg

Comment: Dis is just a duplicate of [How to compile a cpp file directly from vim editor in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61006639/how-to-compile-a-cpp-file-directly-from-vim-editor-in-windows), with almost the same wording too.

Answer (score 2):

Probable answer to your problem: give the full paths: `%` for the source and `%<` for the executable.

Also, please, copy the message,  avoid screenshots.

And finally, you should have a look at this question from this morning... IOW, prefer using quickfix feature. [How to compile a cpp file directly from vim editor in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61006639/how-to-compile-a-cpp-file-directly-from-vim-editor-in-windows/61007827#61007827)

Regarding the execution on the current (monofile) program, it's

```
:!./%<
" or
:term ./%<
```

(you may have to add `.exe` after `%<`. IIRC, this is not necessary)